# Merging multi part answer for a question?

Tags: discussion, support

If there is a multiple part answer for question what would be the best way to merge them?

On the question [Is there a way to search for files by hash value?](https://superuser.com/questions/692603/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-files-by-hash-value) there are two answers by the user [user746340](https://superuser.com/users/746340/user746340) ([Part1](https://superuser.com/a/1226594/619267),[Part2](https://superuser.com/a/1226597/619267)). Aside from the fact that they're really similar to an already existing answer and should probably be a comment, how should someone go about having them merged?

It's an anonymous user so my guess would be that it's unlikely that he will return and actually merge them himself. Should I just do the edit or should a flag be raised for a moderator or should I just leave it alone?

Comment: If the user was 100% definitely the same I'd consider editing one into the other. The problem is that they have different user numbers and the gravatar is also different suggesting that the email used is different so they *could* be different people. This in one reason I'd like to see us switch from allowing unregistered "guest" accounts to full accounts only.